# Tell IntelliJ that XML attributes are functions and parameters

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm working with an in-house system where XML attributes are used to signal PHP function calls.

I know IntelliJ can support custom languages through plugins.

Is there a quickstart or a simple method to get IntelliJ to recognise the calling function based on a `xml attribute` so that it can perform code completion, error detection and `go to definition` services?

Comment: In case if you have not seen these general links, check them first: 1) http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/welcome.html 2) http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/faq.html 3) https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development If you have seen some plugin that does that (similar things), see if it's open source...

Comment: You can also check out existing Language injection patterns at File | Settings | Editor | Language Injections & try to create your own.